# Plone error caused by folder name

Tags: plone

I am running a pretty much unmodified instance of Plone 5.0.

I created a lot of folders today, one of which was named "Layout" in a parent folder "Design", which was in the root folder.

This Layout folder caused an error in the view of the Design folder. All I see is the error page

> We’re sorry, but there seems to be an error…
>
> The error has been logged as entry number 1470387402.080.1605824509.
>
> If you need to report this to the 
>                       Site Administration, please include this entry number in your message.

The error log of Plone has the following entry:

> Exception Type

```
RuntimeError
```

> Exception Value

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

> Traceback (innermost last):

```
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 444, in traverse
Module Products.CMFCore.DynamicType, line 147, in __before_publishing_traverse__
Module Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.fti, line 236, in queryMethodID
Module Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.fti, line 197, in defaultView
Module Products.CMFPlone.PloneTool, line 771, in browserDefault
Module Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.browserdefault, line 99, in getLayout
Module Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.fti, line 136, in getViewMethod
Module Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.browserdefault, line 72, in __call__
Module Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.browserdefault, line 72, in __call__
Module Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.browserdefault, line 72, in __call__
Module Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.browserdefault, line 72, in __call__
Module Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.browserdefault, line 72, in __call__
```

and goes on for a couple of dozen identical calls.

This only happens with this specific folder. I deleted it and created it again: same error. All other folders work fine, even much deeper folder structures work fine.

Any idea what is wrong with this specific folder name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes this happen with Plone due to [acquisition](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/serving/traversing.html#acquisition-effect).

Some names are reserved (looking at your traceback the issue seems related to the view selection, and Layout is in fact a dangerous name).

Plone itself protects you from creating some bad ids but it can cover all the cases.

Another common case with this type of issue is calling a catalog index "data", or calling a content like a catalog index.

Just use a different name.

Comment: This is a regression from Plone 4 that needs to be fixed. Although "dangerous", `Layout` is a very usual name for organizing contents and is probably going to be wanted to be used by Plone users all over the globe - even in languages other than English (in pt-br, for instance). I was able to reproduce the error in 5.0.5 also by adding a Layout folder in site root and changing the latter's view to Standard (and also breaks toolbar on folder contents). As you figured, `RuntimeError: layout attribute exists on <PloneSite at Plone> and is no string: <type 'Acquisition.ImplicitAcquisitionWrapper'>`